# window.scrollTo(0,0) - object is not a function

Tags: jquery

Why am I getting this error?

In console I can place a debugger at the error and type:

```
window
Window {top: Window, window: Window, location: Location, external: Object, chrome: Object…}
window.scrollTo(0,0)
TypeError: object is not a function
```

Why am I getting an error here? This was working fine the other day.

Here's the code:

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#customer-info-submit').click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      var form = $('form#customer_information');
      var i = 0;
      $.each(required_fields, function(field, response) {
        i++;
        if( '' == $('#'+field).val() ) {
          debugger;
          $(gateway_message).html(response);
          window.scrollTo(0,0);
          return false;
        }
        console.log(i);
        if( i == 9 ) {
          debugger;
        }
        if( i == 12 ) { // 12 is the count of attributes of required fields
          if( !$('#terms_agreement').is(':checked') ) {

            $(gateway_message).html('You did not accept the Terms and Conditions.');
            window.scrollTo(0,0);
          } else {
            form.submit();
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: and your jquery code?

Comment: Do you have a global variable named `scrollTo` somewhere? (Watch out for missing `var` keywords.)

Comment: @RobertRozas What would you recommend?

Comment: If you just type `window.scrollTo` in the console, what do you get back? It should say `function scrollTo() { [native code] }` in Chrome.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I get null!

Comment: As Frédéric Hamidi implied, you must have wiped out `window.scrollTo` with an accidental assignment to it. Start a fresh browser with only the code shown (e.g. in a JSFiddle) and try again.

Comment: If the symptoms persist, search the whole code that runs in the page for `/scrollTo\s*=/`. You should find the culprit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant to use `scrollTop(0)` and not `scrollTo(0)` for your jQuery version: http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/

e.g. `$('body').scrollTop(0);`

As you for your `window.scrollTo(0,0)`, I tried in in the Chrome F12 debugger window and works just fine.

**Side note:**

Use the shortcut DOM ready event handler to combined your IIFE (which is only guaranteeing the $ scope) and `$(document).ready();`

e.g.

```
jQuery(function($){
       // your jQuery code using $
});
```

*jQuery passes the jQuery instance (itself) as a first parameter in the shortcut DOM ready handler.*

Comment: Yup, this invalidates Amin's answer, but the questioner is using `window.scrollTo()` (DOM method), which is indeed supposed to be a function.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Yes. As I noted, his console code works just fine in Chrome here. Hard to guess what could interfere with that. :/

Comment: Yes, I only have one rational explanation for that, stated it in the comments, and am still waiting for the questioner to follow up.

Comment: @Frédéric Hamidi: Certainly possible. Good suggestion. I will add some comments on ways to check that.

Comment: Some pop-up blockers can interfere with this. Try turning any pop-up blockers off and see if the problem persists.

Comment: Comments with downvotes would add value. Drive-by downvotes are however completely useless.